Kalman gain for control system $(A, B, C, D)$
I saw many publications with descriptions of Kalman matrix gain for a system of three matrices $(A, B, C)$ like
$$\begin{align}
x_{k + 1} &= A x_{k} + B {u_k} \\
y_{k} &= C x_{k} 
\end{align}$$
but in general, in control theory, there is a state space system of form with four matrices $(A, B, C, D)$
$$\begin{align}
x_{k + 1} &= A x_{k} + B {u_k} \\
y_{k} &= C x_{k} + D u_{k}.
\end{align}$$
What would a derivation of Kalman gain $K$ (through matrices $R, P, Q$) look like in that case?

It doesn't change anything. In the kalman filter update step one has the received measurement $y$, and also produces an estimated measurement $\hat{y}$ as a function of the estimated state $\hat{x}$. If the true measurement model is $y = Cx + Du$, and the control input $u$ is known, then your predicted measurement would be $\hat{y} = C \hat{x} + Du$. The filter only makes use of the difference between the measurements $(y - \hat{y})$, so the control input term cancels out.

I answered by myself on this question here
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/95349/55473
Shortly, Kalman algorithm remain the same, changed only predicted measurement calculation $\hat{y} = C \hat{x} + D u$ as mentioned also in Dawson Beatty answer.

I'm glad you figured it out, but please don't post the same question to multiple stack exchange sites.

The added $D$ matrix only affects how one should calculate the expected output, and there might be a correlation between the process and observation noise (which is otherwise often assumed to be zero). This is because $u_k$ is deterministic, so one just adds this to the expected output. However, the process noise often enters the system dynamics in a similar way as the input $u_k$, causing it to possibly also have a contribution to the output, making the process and observation noise correlated.
For completeness sake I will also include the process and observation noise $w_k\sim\mathcal{N}(0,Q_k)$ and $v_k\sim\mathcal{N}(0,R_k)$ respectively in the assumed model, which are correlated with each other according to $\mathbb{E}(w_k\,v_j^\top) = N_k\,\delta_{kj}$, with $\delta_{kj}$ the Kronecker delta function. I will also generalize the model to a linear time-varying system, which drives the process that we want to filter. This combines to the following
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= A_k\,x_{k} + B_k\,u_k + w_k, \\
y_{k} &= C_k\,x_{k} + D_k\,u_k + v_k.
\end{align}
The prediction step for updating the state remains the same. However, $x_{k+1}$ and $y_k$ are both correlated with $w_k$, which means that $\hat{x}_{k+1|k}$ does have a covariance that is slightly different, resulting in
\begin{align}
\hat{x}_{k+1|k} &= A_k\,\hat{x}_{k|k} + B_k\,u_k, \\
P_{k+1|k} &= A_k\,P_{k|k}\,A_k^\top + Q_k \color{red}{- N_k\,K_k^\top A_k^\top - A_k\,K_k\,N_k^\top},
\end{align}
note that the Kalman gain $K_k$ used in the expression for $P_{k+1|k}$ is the gain obtained in the previous correction step. The calculation of the predicted output $\hat{y}_{k|k-1}$ and thus the output error $\tilde{y}_k$ is changed slightly to the following
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_{k|k-1} &= C_k\,\hat{x}_{k|k-1} \color{blue}{+ D_k\,u_k}, \\
\tilde{y}_k &= y_{k} - \hat{y}_{k|k-1}.
\end{align}
The state correction equation remains the same, but the addition of the cross-correlation in noise does change the value of the Kalman gain $K_k$ and the update to the state covariance $P_{k|k}$ a little, as shown below
\begin{align}
K_k &= \left(P_{k|k-1} C_k^\top \color{red}{+ A_k^{-1} N_k}\right) \left(C_k\,P_{k|k-1}\,C_k^\top + R_k\right)^{-1}, \\
\hat{x}_{k|k} &= \hat{x}_{k|k-1} + K_k\,\tilde{y}_k, \\
P_{k|k} &= (I - K_k\,C_k)\,P_{k|k-1} \color{red}{+ A_k^{-1} N_k\,K_k^\top}.
\end{align}
Note that in the above equations, in order to compare it more easily to the standard Kalman filter, I highlighted in blue the change due to the introduction of the feedthrough matrix $D_k$ and in red the changes due to the introduction of the cross-correlation between the process and measurement noise $N_k$.

It can be noted that the inverse of state transition matrix $A_k^{-1}$ might not exist. In that case, one can combine the prediction and correction steps into one step
\begin{align}
L_k &= \left(A_k\,P_{k|k-1} C_k^\top + N_k\right) \left(C_k\,P_{k|k-1}\,C_k^\top + R_k\right)^{-1}, \\
\hat{x}_{k+1|k} &= A_k\,\hat{x}_{k|k-1} + L_k\,\tilde{y}_k, \\
P_{k+1|k} &= A_k\,P_{k|k-1}\,A_k^\top + Q_k - L_k \left(C_k\,P_{k|k-1} A_k^\top + N_k^\top\right).
\end{align}
